# AWS Lambda: Does Language change affect RAM(Memory) Usage or cost of the service?

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

AWS Lambda has 2 different programming language options and as you know while we are speaking about the Lambda, RAM(Memory) usage is very important thing.

Is there any difference about Node.js's RAM usage and Python's RAM Usage?

If there is a something like when we use it, it will be more cost efficient, I'm thinking about using only that language. Also maybe Node.js execution can be much faster than Python and because of that RAM disadvantage could not be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [AWS Lambda pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/):

> Duration is calculated from the time your code begins executing until it returns or otherwise terminates, rounded up to the nearest 100ms. The price depends on the amount of memory you allocate to your function. You are charged $0.00001667 for every GB-second used.

RAM usage for the language runtime does not *directly* affect the pricing.

You choose the RAM *statically* when you define your Lambda function, and that does have an effect on the pricing, but it done *once*, and all invocation get the same RAM amount, and cost accordingly.

However - you do pay more according to the **duration** of the invocation.

I would *expect* Amazon not to charge you for the time it takes to bootstrap the environment - the pricing page does say *"from the time **your code** begins executing until it returns"*.
(this is speculative, of course, but it wouldn't look fair to charge for the overhead)

Different languages and runtimes can have [different execution times](https://bjpelc.wordpress.com/2015/01/10/yet-another-language-speed-test-counting-primes-c-c-java-javascript-php-python-and-ruby-2/), even for identical (or idiomatic) programs.
This difference in speed can, and will, affect the price.

Comment: I mean if i don't need that much RAM, simply i won't dedicate it. It's like if i wrote the code in Node.JS ( we need 100 MB RAM dedication ) else if it's Python ( we need 75 MB RAM Dedication )